# PHP ImageMagick getImageType returns array... how to associate with type?

Tags: php, imagemagick

The PHP ImageMagick function getImageType returns an array number, but I can't find any documentation as to how to actually associate this with a type.

I need to know if it's a png, jpg, gif, etc...

```
$image = new Imagick("test.png");
$ext = $image->getImageType();

// prints 6
echo $ext
```

Comment: why do you want to know the format  ? you can set the format to to whatever so i guess i dont' know why you want the format ?

Comment: For one thing, if it's a transparent png I don't want to save it as a jpg, but if it's a jpg, I don't want to increase the size be saving as a png.

Comment: have any of these answers resolve your problem ?

Comment: @mcgrailm: no they have not. I've come up with a secondary solution which I will post later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest this way which works fine for me

```
    $image = new Imagick('image.gif');
    $image->getImageFormat();
    echo $image; // output GIF
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `getimagesize`to get the image size and type. Image type is return at index pos 2.

1 = GIF, 2 = JPG, 3 = PNG, 4 = SWF, 5 = PSD, 6 = BMP, 7 = TIFF(orden de bytes intel), 8 = TIFF(orden de bytes motorola), 9 = JPC, 10 = JP2, 11 = JPX, 12 = JB2, 13 = SWC, 14 = IFF, 15 = WBMP, 16 = XBM.

**Php doc for getimagesize()** - http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

**Example usage:**

```
list($width, $height, $type) = getimagesize('herp-derp.png');
echo $type;
```

Edit: Useful comment from phpdoc notes....

```
In addition to thomporter's quick-reference of the output array, here's what PHP 4.4.0 does:

Array[0] = Width 
Array[1] = Height
Array[2] = Image Type Flag
Array[3] = width="xxx" height="xxx"
Array[bits] = bits
Array[channels] = channels
Array[mime] = mime-type
```

**Edit:** `getImageType` returns one of IMAGICK_TYPE_* constants (http://www.phpf1.com/manual/imagick-getimagetype.html). You can find the list of constants here - http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.constants.php .

**IMGTYPE constants**

imagick::IMGTYPE_UNDEFINED (integer)
imagick::IMGTYPE_BILEVEL (integer)
imagick::IMGTYPE_GRAYSCALE (integer)
imagick::IMGTYPE_GRAYSCALEMATTE (integer)
imagick::IMGTYPE_PALETTE (integer)
imagick::IMGTYPE_PALETTEMATTE (integer)
imagick::IMGTYPE_TRUECOLOR (integer)
imagick::IMGTYPE_TRUECOLORMATTE (integer)
imagick::IMGTYPE_COLORSEPARATION (integer)
imagick::IMGTYPE_COLORSEPARATIONMATTE (integer)
imagick::IMGTYPE_OPTIMIZE (integer)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to use the ImageMagick function. But thanks though.

Comment: @kylex, I included the list of imagetype contants it returns above.

Answer (score 1):

A good and quick way to validate images is:

```
$ identify -format %m image.jpg
JPEG
```

in PHP:

```
<?php
// If its not a valid image, returns an empty string.
$image_type = exec('identify -format %m image.jpg');
?>
```

More about using -format: [imagemagick formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php)

Answer (score 0):

getImageType() returns an array if it's successful as per this page.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-getimagetype.php

maybe try a vardump or a print_r  of $ext?

Comment: print_r of $ext returns 6 as does just echoing $ext

Comment: The documentation says it returns an integer, not an array. (It may be the documentation has been changed, but it doesn't return an array anymore.)

Answer (score -1):

this is the best I could do for you this will give you the extension and you can use that first before you load image

```
$path_parts  = pathinfo("test.png");
echo $path_parts ['extension'];
```